# Is there a python module that automatically generates javascript code for asynchronous loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, asynchronous

I have a webapp that contains several more or less independent elements on each page. I would like that on certain pages certain elements by loaded asynchronously (to make server response faster). This can be done by loading these elements asynchronously with javascript. I was wondering is a python module exists which generates this javascript code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) and [brython](http://www.brython.info/) let you write some kinds of client-side code in Python.